# How to implement CRUD operation with jQUery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, crud

I've just created a (classical) users list using CRUD with only PHP, (bootstrap) and MySQL. Everything works OK.

But when I try to use jQuery to avoid refresh the pages when making the operations I encounter some errors that I can't solve.

I'm able to create/insert new users without problems, but deletion works only once. I can delete a record by clicking the button and it disappears from the list on the page and from the database and it shows the new list without the just deleted user. But when I try to delete another user in the list nothing occurs. And the bootstrap modal loads always with the data of the previous deleted user.

I think it's something with reseting a variable, but I'm unable to find what I have to do.

Here the files involved in the operation:

Just an *excerpt* of **index.php** where the list/table is echoed.

```
<?php
require_once 'database.php';
include 'crud-read.php';
include 'modal-delete-user.php';
?>
<html>
        </div>
          <?php echo $output; ?>
      </div>

  <?php include 'scripts.php';?>
</html>
```

**modal-delete-user.php** (This is a part of the alert modal to confirm deletion)

```
<!-- Modal Delete User -->
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="form-delete-user">
          <input id="delete-user-id" name="delete-user-id" type="text">

        <p>
          Really delete?
          <strong>
            <span id="delete-user-forename"></span>
            <span id="delete-user-name"></span>
          </strong>?
        </p>
        <p>It cannot be undone!</p>

      </div>

        <button class="btn btn-danger" id="delete-user-submit-button" type="input">
          <i class="fas fa-trash-alt fa-2x" data-toggle="tooltip" id="del-confirm-info"
            title="Exclude user"></i>
        </button>
      </form>
```

**crud-read.php** (This is used to select users from database and echo user list on the index.php)

```
<?php
// Read users
$read_query = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($read_query);
$stmt->execute();

$count = 1;
$output .='<tbody>';

while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
  $output .=
    '<tr>
      <td>'.$count.'</td>
      <td>'.$row->forename.'</td>
      <td>'.$row->name.'</td>
      <td><a class="link-edit-user" id="' . $row->id . '" name="' . $row->id . '" href="#">EDIT</a></td>
      <td>
        <a class="link-delete-user text-danger"
          data-target="#modal-delete-user"
          data-id="'.$row->id.'"
          data-forename="'.$row->forename.'"
          data-name="'.$row->name.'"
          data-toggle="modal" href="#">
            <i class="far fa-trash-alt fa-xs"></i>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>';

  $count++;
}

$output .='</tbody>';
```

**crud-delete.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'database.php';

// Delete user
$delete_query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($delete_query);

$id = $_POST['delete-user-id'];

$stmt->bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT); // id is an integer, that's why PARAM_INT

$stmt->execute();

// Read remaining users and echo table on the page
include 'crud-read.php';
echo $output;
```

**scripts.php** (When we click the delete button it opens a modal which asks for delete confirmation. When clicked OK it executes crud-delete.php) PROBLEM: After deleting the user/record it vanish from the list. But when I try to do the same operation once again the modal opens with data of the first deleted user, but the **id** (not from first deleted user, neither from the new clicked user to be deleted).

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Confirm user deletion
    $(".link-delete-user").click(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        var db = $(this).attr('data-id');
        $("#delete-user-id").val(db);
        $("#delete-user-forename").text($(this).attr('data-forename'));
        $("#delete-user-name").text($(this).attr('data-name'));
        $("#modal-delete-user").modal("show");
  });
    // Delete user
    $("#form-delete-user").on('submit', function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "crud-delete.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: $('#form-delete-user').serialize(),
            success: function(resp) {
                $('#form-delete-user')[0].reset();
                $('#modal-delete-user').modal('hide');
                $('#table-users').html(resp);
      }
    });
  });

});
</script>
```

Any tips?

Comment: This question falls in the TMI category.  Consider posting a minimal, complete, verifiable example (MCVE) (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and you stand a better chance of having help for a specific issue.

Comment: Thanks for you comment @YvesLeBorg. I thought that it would be better to show everything. Should I edit it or create a new question?

Comment: @YvesLeBorg let only the essential parts of the code involved in the CRUD operation. Hope it's now conform with the rules. Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the submit button only working once is because when you add an event listener on load, it attaches to every matching button on the screen at that time. But after you reload the list, new buttons are displayed.

Simply change your event listeners to:

```
$(document).on("click",".link-delete-user", function() {

$(document).on("submit","#form-delete-user", function() {
```

Comment: This answer helped e on my issue, thanks for the event listener precision